# Embedding Dependency Frameworks into a Single Dynamic Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, carthage

I have this project that is designed to be used as a Dynamic Framework, named ProjectA.framework.

However, ProjectA depends on other dynamic frameworks, such as Alamofire, Realm, and a couple smaller ones. I want to generate a single .framework file that contains all the frameworks embedded, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Now I have ProjectB, that will use ProjectA as a dynamic framework, and ideally I would like to drag only the ProjectA as a dependency. I'm using Carthage, and it automatically fetches and builds all dependencies, but I'm dragging only ProjectA.framework into the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section.

The projects builds, but gets a runtime error, complaining that one of the third party dependencies was not found.

It is possible to achieve what I am trying to do?
Is this a limitation of carthage or a wrong setup on my side?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm trying to solve the exact same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately not. The only way I could solve it was to link ProjectA dependencies into ProjectB...